# Erasing output from ssh

Tags: python, ssh, cisco

Hi I have a simple script for ssh connection to cisco switch and I want to get running configuration of the device. The script is written to use if necessary multiple `show` commands so I'm using `invoke_shell()`.

To avoid waiting for spacebar to be pressed I've added simple `while` loop.

```
    while str(recieve).__contains__('--More--'):
        channel.send(' \n')
        time.sleep(1)
        recieve = channel.recv(10000)
        final += str(recieve.decode("ascii"))
```

And here is the issue.

If I then printout `final` it shows full `show run` command without `--More--` but when I write contents of `final` variable to file it adds this string:  `--More--`         .

I've tried to look in string with `replace('--More--', '')` but it didn't find that string.

Comment: Why are you calling `__contains__` directly, instead of simply writing `while '--More--' in str(recieve):`?

Comment: Why don't you just disable paging? https://community.cisco.com/t5/small-business-switches/how-to-disable-the-quot-more-quot-prompt-when-running-cli-s-quot/td-p/2080819

Comment: Unfortunately disabling paging is not an option since I want to use this in production enviroment and you can't use anything that has not been approved or justified.